# Immersive Injections whose images are Embedded Submanifolds

Tags: differential-topology

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds where the dimension of $M$ is less than or equal to the dimension of $N$.
Suppose that $F: M \rightarrow N$ is an injective immersion and $F(M)$ is an embedded submanifold, is it the case that $F$ is a smooth embedding?

This question came up when I was studying for my differential topology final with some friends. One of my friends is convinced that this is true, I feel strongly that it's not true. But neither of us could prove or disprove it in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: Do you allow manifolds with boundary?  If so the map from $[0,1)$ wrapping around a circle once is an injective immersion, image is an embedded submanifold, but the map isn't a smooth embedding.

Comment: Bijective immersion is a diffeomorphism (by the inverse function theorem). Your $F$ is a bijective immersion if we see it as a map $M\to F(M)$. Therefore $F:M\to N$ is an embedding. And I hope what I wrote is true :)

Comment: @Jason, I've considered that example actually and we decided to restrict the question to manifolds without boundary.

Comment: @User8268, It's not entirely clear to me where you're using the fact that F(M) is an embedded submanifold. And how you know that the smooth structure F(M) inherits from N lines up with the smooth structure of M.

Comment: @Jacob Schlather: I use this definition: $F:M\to N$ is an embedding iff $F(M)$ is an embedded submanifold and $F:M\to F(M)$ is a diffeomorphism. Here is a possible problem: by an embedded submanifold, do you mean a smooth embedded submanifold, or just topological emb.submfd?

Comment: @User I do mean a smooth embedded submanifold.

Comment: @JS: then I don't see any problem. $F$ being injective immersion implies $F:M\to F(M)$ is a bijective immersion, hence a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @User, Are you implicitly using the fact that F(M) is an embedded submanifold. Because it's not the case that an injective immersion must be a topological embedding, as shown by the figure eight space, etc.

Comment: @JS: I use it quite explicitly. To say that $F:M\to F(M)$ is a bijective immersion I need that $F(M)$ is an immersed submanifold. Then, when we know that $F:M\to F(M)$ is a diffeomorphism, I use the fact that $F(M)$ is an embedded submanifold to conclude that $F:M\to N$ is an embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user8268 is right.  Let me just elaborate a little bit on his argument.

When we talk about the map $F\colon M\to N$, we really mean the composition of maps $M \xrightarrow{G} F(M) \xrightarrow{\iota} N,$ where $G\colon M \to F(M)$ is just the map $F$ with its range restricted, and $\iota\colon F(M) \to N$ is inclusion.

Now, we claim that $G$ is a diffeomorphism and $\iota$ is a smooth embedding, so that $F = \iota \circ G$ is a smooth embedding.

- Since $F\colon M\to N$ is an injective immersion, and since $G$ is continuous, we have that $G\colon M\to F(M)$ is a bijective immersion, and so $G$ is a diffeomorphism.
- Since $F(M)$ is embedded, we have that $\iota\colon F(M) \to N$ is a smooth embedding.

---

Some remarks:

(1) In the case of the Figure 8, what fails is that $\iota$ is not a smooth embedding, but instead an injective immersion.  Note, though, that $G$ is still a diffeomorphism in this case because that is how we *define* both the smooth structure and topology of the Figure 8.

(2) In the first bullet point, we do need the fact that $G\colon M \to F(M)$ is continuous.  Otherwise, we cannot immediately conclude that $G$ is smooth.

For instance, if the Figure 8 were given some weird topology -- neither the topology inherited from $M$ by declaring $G$ a diffeomorphism, nor the topology inherited from $N$ as a subspace, but instead something really weird -- then the map $G$ may fail to be continuous.

So why is $G$ continuous in our case?  Well, since we were given that $F\colon M\to N$ is continuous, and since $F(M)$ carries the subspace topology (by virtue of being embedded), we can conclude that the restricted map $G$ is in fact continuous.

Comment: So if we have an injective immersion $f: M \rightarrow N$ that is not a smooth embedding we can conclude that $F(M)$ is not an embedded submanifold of $N$?

Comment: Yes.  That's equivalent to the question you just asked.  Suppose $F\colon M \to N$ is an injective immersion.  We just proved that if $F(M)$ is an embedded submanifold, then $F$ is a smooth embedding.  The contrapositive is that if $F$ is not a smooth embedding, then $F(M)$ is an not embedded submanifold.

Comment: To clarify: the conclusion is that $F(M)$ is not an embedded submanifold (or even an immersed submanifold) _when given the subspace topology._  However, $F(M)$ may be an immersed submanifold when given other topologies.